# How to work with zip on 2 generators s.t each returns the same item that changes its state overtime

Tags: python

```
from collections import deque

def window(seq, n=2):
    it = iter(seq)
    win = deque((next(it, None) for _ in xrange(n)), maxlen=n)
    yield win
    append = win.append
    for e in it:
        append(e)
        yield win

a=[1,2,3]
b=[2,4,6]


for d in zip(window(a,2),window(b,2)):
    print d
    raw_input("Press Enter to continue...")
```

The output :

> ```
> (deque([2, 3], maxlen=2), deque([4, 6], maxlen=2))
> Press Enter to continue...
> (deque([2, 3], maxlen=2), deque([4, 6], maxlen=2))
> Press Enter to continue...
> ```

What im trying to do here is to capture all the zipped windows of length 2 of `a` and `b`, In other words im expecting the output to be like :

> ```
> (deque([1, 2], maxlen=2), deque([2, 4], maxlen=2))
> Press Enter to continue...
> (deque([2, 3], maxlen=2), deque([4, 6], maxlen=2))
> Press Enter to continue...
> ```

Clearly, `window` is yielding the same object over and over again only with a change in the items it holds, I guess what happens here is that `zip` is creating the iterable before the iteration starts so Im getting the same 2 deque objects zipped twice but the problem is that i get them in their final state.

How would you suggest to fix that without having to yield a copy in the window function?

For example changing window to return a copy would work:

```
def window(seq, n=2):
    it = iter(seq)
    win = deque((next(it, None) for _ in xrange(n)), maxlen=n)
    yield list(win)
    append = win.append
    for e in it:
        append(e)
        yield list(win)
```

But is less efficient, in my use case a and b are huge and ziping all those copies before the iteration is inefficient...

Comment: (try python3 :-) )

Comment: @PRMoureu it works... but is there a solution for python 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid zipping the two iterables *before* beginning the loop, 
use [`itertools.izip`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) instead of `zip` in Python2:

```
import itertools as IT
import collections 

def window(seq, n=2):
    it = iter(seq)
    win = collections.deque((next(it, None) for _ in range(n)), maxlen=n)
    yield win
    append = win.append
    for e in it:
        append(e)
        yield win

a=[1,2,3]
b=[2,4,6]

for d in IT.izip(window(a,2),window(b,2)):
    print(d)
```

yields

```
[deque([1, 2], maxlen=2), deque([2, 4], maxlen=2)]
[deque([2, 3], maxlen=2), deque([4, 6], maxlen=2)]
```

In Python3, `zip` returns an iterator (identical to `itertools.izip` in Python2). This is why the code you posted already works in Python3 without changes.